# Intent Action isn't changing after recalling the activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this `Activity` called `Posting`:

```
<activity
        android:name="Posting"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.emergency.StopDistributing"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.emergency.nothingMuch"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am navigating to this specific activity using action: `com.emergency.nothingMuch`. as demonstrated in the following code:

```
i = new Intent("com.emergency.nothingMuch");
startActivity(i);
```

now in `Posting` class I have a `Button` that when clicked it should bind to a service and get data from it and do some tasks. also a notification will show that by clicking on the notification, the activity will unbind the service and do other tasks.

the notification has a `PendingIntent` to this same `Posting` class but with different action. the following code is:

```
Intent iStop = new Intent("com.emergency.StopDistributing");
PendingIntent stopTrackingPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, iStop, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Stop Tracking", stopTrackingPI);
```

now in `onResume` I have a if statement to check for the Intent Action.

```
if(getIntent().getAction().equals("com.emergency.StopDistributing")) {
        stopPosting();
    }
```

After adding `Log.d` before the if statement. when I press on the notification action. the intent action I get is still `nothingMuch`. it doesn't change to `com.emergency.StopDistributing`.

I also used `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for this activity because I want to modify the existing activity rather than opening a new one.

So why the Intent's action isn't changing when clicked on the notification and how can I fix it. Thanks in advance.

**P.S:** I don't want to use setIntent(iStop); to change it because I have other `PendingIntent`s so I need another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)() method in your Activity to check the action of the Intent, rather than using getIntent(), which will still return the original intent.

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.
>
> An activity will always be paused before receiving a new intent, so
>   you can count on onResume() being called after this method.
>
> **Note that getIntent() still returns the original Intent.** You can use
>   setIntent(Intent) to update it to this new Intent.

Comment: It worked thank you! the getIntent().getAction() returns the old intent Action. However the intent of the `onNewItent()` will return the new Action!! thanks for your fast response.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I thought I had an obscure problem but nope it's apparently super easy!